# get value from outside promise in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I've got the following code:

```
generateFromID: function (icon, width, height, color) {

      path = [];

      iconData.get(icon).then(function (iconP) {

        var path = iconPathCache.generate(iconP);

      });

      console.log(path);

      return this.generate(path, width, height, color);


    },
```

How can i get path outside of .then?

```
console.log(iconData.get(icon));
```

will result in:

```
Promise {$$state: Object}$$state: Object__proto__: Object
```

The code below also doesn't work:

```
return iconData.get(icon).then(function (iconP) {

         return path = iconPathCache.generate(iconP);

      });

      return this.generate(path, width, height, color);
```

Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: what do you mean with "outside .then" ? I think you miss the concept of async execution and $q promise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but I think you are confused about promises and async in general.

I am guessing that the `path` value got from `iconData.get(icon)` needs to be passed to `this.generate`, it can be done by:

```
generateFromID: function (icon, width, height, color) {
  return iconData.get(icon).then(function (iconP) {
    var path = iconPathCache.generate(iconP);
    console.log(path);
    return this.generate(path, width, height, color);
  });
},
```

now `generateFromID` would return a promise.